# Rails - active storage and multi databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6, multi-database-connections

Is is possible to use active storage with multi databases in rails? I have the following models:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end


class OtherRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { writing: :other_db }
end


class SomeModel < OtherRecord
  has_many_attached :files
end
```

I've added active storage migrations scoped to the secondary database and necessary tables were created there but ActiveStorage seems to look for tables in primary database. Have anyone a solution for that?